# how to start a script with root privilege on boot?

Tags: boot, cron, root, delay

I tried with systemctl and with crontab without success.

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cyberghostvpn --country-code AU --city Brisbane --connect
```

rights :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pat pat 71 nov 28 13:04 ghoststart.sh
```

my crontab that i have run this way : `sudo crontab -e`

```
@reboot sleep 120; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh
```

i can run the script in terminal no problem : `sudo sh ghoststart.sh`

syslog cron :

```
Nov 28 13:17:57 mrpotato cron[679]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov 28 13:17:57 mrpotato cron[679]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Nov 28 13:17:59 mrpotato CRON[726]: (root) CMD (sh /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh)
Nov 28 13:24:04 mrpotato cron[658]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov 28 13:24:04 mrpotato cron[658]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

seems like cron stopped working after 13:24:04, beacause ive done attempt after that

edit 2:
based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85558/verify-if-crontab-works) i have tried

```
root@mrpotato:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)"
Prepare OpenVPN connection ...
Please Install "openvpn" first!
```

it gives me the same error if i wasnt root, obviouly openvpn is installed

3rd edit:

if i do this i get no error .

```
pat@mrpotato:~$ sudo /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)"
```

but if i do this i get one:

```
root@mrpotato:~# /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)"
```

the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 580, in <module>
  File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 346, in main
  File "libs/config.py", line 45, in __init__
  File "libs/config.py", line 112, in readConfigFile
Exception: The config file "/home/root/.cyberghost/config.ini" does not exist!
[3845] Failed to execute script cyberghostvpn
```

config.ini exist in `/home/pat/.cyberghost/`

cron must be running the script as root and not with sudo... or something like that, the script gets the file from the running user... if that make sense.

i have no idea how to solve that !

Comment: Could you look up in the journal/syslog if there are any error messages from your previous attempts which might help to track down the reason for the failure?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ghoststart.sh` script (or the `cyberghostvpn` thing within it) is trying to start OpenVPN by calling the `openvpn` executable.  This executable is not found in the `$PATH` within the script.  Use `command -v openvpn` in a terminal to locate the path of the executable.

If your `openvpn` executable is located in `/usr/sbin`, you may write your crontab schedule as

```
@reboot sleep 120 && PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin" /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh
```

Your "3rd edit" also indicates that the tool is looking for a configuration file in the home directory of the user starting the tool.  You say you have this file in the home directory of `pat` and not in the home directory of `root`.

You have two options here:

1. Move the configuration file to where the tool expects to find it, or
2. Tell the tool where `HOME` is.

The second option could be done by modifying the cron job to say

```
@reboot sleep 120 && HOME=/home/pat PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin" /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh
```

Comment: /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)" that is working now

but not with cron, logs are not helpful : Nov 29 13:25:01 mrpotato CRON[2378]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)

Comment: cyberghostvpn is written in python should i add that path too

Comment: @Patcmpro 1) I'm not surprised that your command does not work from cron, this is why I gave you the suggestion in my answer. 2) I have removed the second suggestion as it was confusing.

Comment: i did that and its still not working... ill try again

Comment: @Patcmpro Do you still get the same error message about not finding `openvpn`? Do you know where the `openvpn` executable file is located?

Comment: if you read my first comment you will read that when i run the command in the shell i dont get an error, it is working... but with cron it is not, but let me be sure , ill try again

Comment: @Patcmpro Your first comment seems to indicate that you ran `command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1` in the cron job (which sems unrelated to your question). I suggested using the `command -v` command in a terminal to find out where the `openvpn` executable was located.

Comment: ok iam not retarded ... i did located the exec of openvpn which is in sbin then i tried to add the path in cron and in the script.... when i add the path in the script and i run that command ( /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)" )    which is close to what cron do , IT IS WORKING, ITS A GOOD THING ! but if i add the path in crontab ITS NOT WORKING , and if i add the path in the script but not in cron it is NOT WORKING... i hope i was clear ? ... now , cyberghostvpn is written in python should i add that path aswell ?

Comment: @Patcmpro I still don't see _any indication_ of you actually using the cron job specification in my answer. There is no mentioning of `export` or `/bin/sh -c` in my answer.  There is no mentioning of `/usr/sbin` in your attempted command.

Comment: that error is from the shell...
root@mrpotato:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)"
Prepare OpenVPN connection ...
Please Install "openvpn" first!

Comment: with cron i have nothing to indicate what is hapennig i just know that iam not connected to my vpn

Comment: @Patcmpro Please, forget about your command. Use the crontab schedule that I actually show in my answer: `@reboot sleep 120 && PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin" /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh`  If there is any output from this command, the cron daemon would send it to you in an email (to the local account that owns the crontab, probably root).

Comment: well in /var/mail... i have only the user pat ... theres no root.... and of course in pat theres nothing related to cron

Comment: i made a 3rd edit with what the problem could be

Comment: @Patcmpro See updated answer. I would also appreciate it if you were to actually try the answer I have written (not the command that you keep repeating; it obviously does not work).

Comment: ok i tied twice and it does not work... as i mentioned , the command iam trying to run which run in certain circumstances is pretty close to what cron do ... so if that command works it is very likely to work in cron

Answer (score 0):

> root@mrpotato:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin;/home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh

Where is located your openvpn binary ?  On my Debian, it is in `/usr/sbin` which isn't part of the PATH variable you passed to your script... which explain the error you met.

Comment: yes its located at /usr/sbin

Comment: root@mrpotato:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin;/usr/sbin/ /home/pat/Documents/cyberghost/ghoststart.sh </dev/null)"

/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/: Permission denied

Comment: You have a `;` in the `PATH` (should be `:`).